# Error "Failed to initialize a region" while creating google cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy cloud functions in production environment after testing it in test environment. Everything in test environment worked fine. But in prod environment when I crate cloud function is get following error

> Failed to initialize a region

The complete stackdriver log is here:

```
{
 protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"    
  status: {
   code: 13     
   message: "Failed to initialize a region"     
  }
  serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"    
  methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1beta2.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction"    
  resourceName: "projects/**********/locations/us-central1/functions/load-to-bigquery"    
 }
 insertId: "54F77BC951659.A03E406.770C4DE6"   
 resource: {
  type: "cloud_function"
  labels: {
   project_id: "**********"     
   region: "us-central1"     
   function_name: "load-to-bigquery"     
  }
 }
 timestamp: "2017-05-14T08:29:27.142Z"   
 severity: "ERROR"   
 logName: "projects/********/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"   
 operation: {
  id: "operations/dWRjb2xsZWN0L3VzLWNlbnRyYWwxL3VkYy10by1icS9NaXRlVlI2MW1xbw"    
  producer: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"    
  last: true    
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "2017-05-14T08:29:28.495542553Z"   
}
```

> I wanted to know what could be the cause of error? Both environments are quite similar and I have same permission (Project editor) in both environment.

Comment: @user6733196 Your project turned out to be very old, used during alpha testing, so some setup was incorrect. Please try deleting the functions now.
I'm closing the issue now, but please reopen if it still fails. more info you can check at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67027944

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the Cloud Functions API was enabled in your Google Cloud Platform project while the product was in Alpha and was somehow missed during the migration. If that's the case and you are still being affected by this issue you should disable and re-enable the Cloud Function API on your project, which first requires deleting all of your functions.

If you have issues deleting your functions or re-enabling the API, you should [create an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=802601) so the product team can help you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How could my answer to be reworded to be a proper answer? I am very confident that this is the issue affecting the author given that recent cases [(1)](https://issuetracker.google.com/62523682) [(2)](https://issuetracker.google.com/62430025) of users reporting this error were stuck with the Alpha version of the API. It is also the only case in which this error message has been encountered for Cloud Functions.

Comment: In general, stuff like this is best left as a comment (or series of them) on the question itself, and most of the time, when people run into non-persistent bugs like these, the question is closed as non-reproducible after it's fixed, since it doesn't really provide future value. If you posted this as a comment, I would definitely upvote it, though.